# Jquery functions - Ignore particular link within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following single page site uses a waypoint script to navigate and highlight nav items - http://www.jbleitch.co.uk/dt/

It works well - the issue is that we need to alter a link to navigate to an external website - but the script prevents default on any links - so its reasonably complicated!

this is the original script -

```
 //Cache some variables
var links = $('.navigation').find('li');
slide = $('.slide');
button = $('.button');
mywindow = $(window);
htmlbody = $('html,body');
var dataslider = 1;
var clicked = false;
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
var narrow = (windowWidth <= 1000);
var navblock = $('.navBlock');
var dataslide = 1;
var myDirection = 'down';
var curSlide = 0;

slide.waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction === "down") {
        dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
        curslide = dataslide;
        if (narrow) {
            navScroll(dataslide);
        }

        $('.navigation li[data-slide="' + dataslide +   '"]').addClass('active').prev().removeClass('active');

    }
}, {
    offset: '25%'
}).waypoint(function (direction) {
    if (direction === "up") {
        dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
        curslide = dataslide;
        if (narrow) {
            navScroll(dataslide);
        }

        links.removeClass('active');
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active');
    }
}, {
    offset: '-25%'
});

//waypoints doesnt detect the first slide when user scrolls back up to the top so we add this little bit of code, that removes the class
//from navigation link slide 2 and adds it to navigation link slide 1.
mywindow.scroll(function () {
    if (mywindow.scrollTop() == 0) {
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="1"]').addClass('active');
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="2"]').removeClass('active');
    }

    //if (dataslide === 0 && $('.slide[data-slide=2]').offset().top > 10) {
    //    navblock.hide();
    //}
});

//Create a function that will be passed a slide number and then will scroll to that slide using jquerys animate. The Jquery
//easing plugin is also used, so we passed in the easing method of 'easeInOutQuint' which is available throught the plugin.
function goToByScroll(dataslide) {
    //alert(myDirection);
    //alert(dataslide + ' ' + curSlide);
    var scrollto = $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top
    //if (dataslide > curSlide) {
    //    scrollto = scrollto + 1;
    //    //alert("down");
    //}
    //else if (dataslide < curSlide) {
    //    //alert("up");
    //    scrollto = scrollto - 1;
    //}
    htmlbody.stop().animate({
        scrollTop: scrollto
    }, 3200, 'swing', function () {
        if (narrow) {
            navScroll(dataslide);
        }
        else {
            navblock.removeClass('nofix');
            navblock.removeAttr('style');
        }
        curSlide = dataslide
    });

    //setTimeout(function () {  }, 3300);

}

//When the user clicks on the navigation links, get the data-slide attribute value of the link and pass that variable to the goToByScroll function
links.click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    dataslider = $(this).attr('data-slide');
   clicked = true;
    if (narrow) {
        navblock.fadeOut();
    }
    goToByScroll(dataslider);
});

//When the user clicks on the button, get the get the data-slide attribute value of the button and pass that variable to the goToByScroll function
button.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslider = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    clicked = true;
    if (narrow) {
        navblock.fadeOut();
    }
    goToByScroll(dataslider);

});

function navScroll(dataslide) {
    //alert('div[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]');
    var slidepos = $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset.top;
    navblock.addClass('nofix');
    //navblock.hide();
    navblock.css({ top: $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top });
    navblock.fadeIn('slow');
    //alert(navblock.attr('class'));
    //alert("nav scroll");
}
```

this is the navigation list -

```
<ul class="navigation">

                        <li data-slide="2" class="nv1 active">Services</li>

                        <li data-slide="3" class="nv2">Fees &amp; Reporting</li>

                        <li data-slide="4" class="nv3">News</li>

                        <li data-slide="5" class="nv4">Meet the Team</li>

                        <li data-slide="5" class="nv4"><a style="color:inherit!important; text-decoration:none" href="http:www.othersite.com">Careers</a></li>

                        <li data-slide="7" class="nv6">Our Credentials</li>

                        <li data-slide="8" class="nv7">Contact</li>

            </ul>
```

I need to change the careers site to navigate to the url but the script above prevents it from doing so - I have tried the following alteration -

```
 links.click(function (e) {
    if(!=".nv5"){
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslider = $(this).attr('data-slide');
   clicked = true;
    if (narrow) {
        navblock.fadeOut();
    }
    goToByScroll(dataslider);
    }
   });
```

But no luck - can anyone suggest an alternative!?

Comment: not clear with question can you explain clearly ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually I get the info i want in a data attribute, and then i can make anything

```
<li data-slide="5" class="nv4">
     <a href="#" data-ref="http:www.othersite.com">Careers</a>
</li>
```

Then, in the click handler:

```
links.click(function (e) {
    if($(this).attr("data-ref") != ""){
        //get the link
        var link = $(this).attr("data-ref");
        //go to link
        window.location.href = link;
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        dataslider = $(this).attr('data-slide');
        clicked = true;
        if (narrow) {
            navblock.fadeOut();
        }
        goToByScroll(dataslider);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a condition to your link method whereby it will check for an attribute or some other property and follow through with the link if required

You were on the right track with your initial attempt. This should work

```
links.click(function (e) {
    if(!$(this).hasClass("nv5")){
        e.preventDefault();
        dataslider = $(this).attr('data-slide');
        clicked = true;
        if (narrow) {
            navblock.fadeOut();
        }
        goToByScroll(dataslider);
    }
});
```

That's assuming you have the class `nv5` on the links you want to remove the behaviour from